# Which Windows versions have preinstalled MSINET.OCX control

Tags: windows, activex, msinet

I have an old VB6 application that depends on MSINET.OCX. I'd like to know if I can distribute this application without registering MSINET OCX component. My target OSes are XP, Vista and Windows 7. Do all of them have this component preinstalled?

Comment: If you are using HTTP, the WinHTTP library ships in all of those OSs. The MSINET.OCX is pretty old and crusty, however it offers FTP which other standard VB6 components and Windows components do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this information from [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistaact/thread/ee5696aa-c94d-481a-bbbe-4dad30ccae7f/) helps you. The short of it seems to be that it does not come preinstalled, it is installed when you install an application that uses it.  You will need to include it in your installation.

Comment: True, it never shipped as part of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

It's not shipping with the OS. It is however delivered with Visual Basic. You must include it within your application setup. For details on Vista and Win7 support see: [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx)